# Mysql Workbench Model table height issue

Tags: macos, preferences, mysql

having a weird issue with the model editor in mysql workbench. All the table name height are far too big. Its making working with the editor completely impossible. I've search and googled and can't find any solutions. Also been through the preferences and can't see any options to solve this.

I'm on `OS X 10.7.5` and `Workbench 6.1.6`. A screen shot is the best way to describe what is happening...
[image]

As you can see the tables 'address' and 'customer' have heights in the box titles that do not suit, resizing left/right/up/down does not make a difference. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should try upgrading to 6.3